# Continueing body when scrolling past top in browser

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am making this website: http://charlottebrand.nl/BFA/index.html
As you can see the design is made so that the word 'ARENA' is being cut off at the top and bottom of each section.

What I want is this: when you scroll up past the top (this elastic effect of the browser is triggered) you'll be able to see the whole word 'ARENA' instead of it being cut off, as it is now.

I've tried to give the body more padding, open the page at the right height and then added a snap scroll to create the elastic effect, but all in vain. It's always too glitchy! I feel like there should be a simple solution. Something in the line of rubber band scroll?

Help is much appreciated!

PS Here you can see my latest try: http://charlottebrand.nl/BFA/index2.html

Comment: I think when it comes to actual content you might be out of luck. Using a `background-image` on the body might work though.